# Google is not open in any browser

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, firefox, ssl

www.google.com will not open in any browser.

I try to open `www.google.com` in `Google Chrome` and also in `Firefox` but it given below error message.

**In Google chrome I got this error message**

> SSL connection error
>
> Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a
>   problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client
>   authentication certificate that you don't have. Error code:
>   ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

**In Firefox I got this error message**

> The connection was reset
>       The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>           The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
>       moments.   If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
>       connection.   If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
>       that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

Other sites work fine with this both these browsers. I can `ping` www.google.com and get a good response.

My computer local time also correct.

Other `https` site is work fine.

My OS is `Window XP`.

How can I solve this type of problem?

Comment: what happens when you ping 8.8.8.8 ?

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn it given good response.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a 3 yr old problem with a web site that can no longer be replicated.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your local time is wrong.

Comment: my local time also correct as well as all other https site is work fine.

Comment: actually, yeah, that would cause ssl to break. And, one reason or the time to be wrong is a dead bios battery.  Connection is reset is a different problem might be an ISP thing

Comment: time is work fine no dead bios battery issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

Sign out or open google.com in incognito mode. google.com should now be in http instead of https. Does the problem still persist?

Comment: incognito mode. google.com is open ne work but in normal mode it not work and i want to open google in normal mode.

Comment: what about signing out and using http? If it still doesn't work try deleting cookies from google.com

Comment: what about signing out and using http ? this is not work .

Comment: and how can i delete google.com cookies ?

Comment: 1. press F12 to open developer tools
2. from the tabs choose resources
3. click cookies
4. click google.com then the name of cookies to the right
5. press DEL on keyboard for all

Comment: thank yuo but it not work for me . :-(